# Don't show a comment notification if you have already seen the comment

Tags: feature-request, comments

So, i just figured out something really small, and i'd want to see if i'm just a lunatic or if other people are bothered by that aswell.

When you're on a question/answer page and (thanks to the auto-updates) you manually click to see a comment made **for you** (ie on your question / answer):

[image]

The issue is that you still get to see the notification in your navbar.
So here's my suggestion :

**If you click on that "show 1 more comment" link, make the notification dissapear from your navbar.**

Comment: I doubt this will get implemented anytime soon. It isn't really that important and would be a decent amount of work for a minuscule return.

Comment: @CarrieKendallr First of, Thanks for your feedback ! And yeah, it's just a minor thing, but i'd rather let it roll there instead of just keeping it for myself :P

Comment: Just consider the technical side of making what you propose happen. ;) Not really worth the effort.

Comment: @TravisJ I don't think this would be much harder than let’s say the reputation changebar that can unlit itself if you checked in another tab

Comment: When you click on the notification icon it means that you confirm it to be seen. There are situations that you are not aware that let say an answer is added and you close the tab which leads you to miss the answer.

Comment: What I found much more useful would be to make notifications disappear that are for comments *that I have just answered to*.

Comment: Another minor thing related, but really not that important (and maybe not even StackExchange's fault), is that while subscribed to RSS updates on my activity (comments, etc.), I sometimes receive entries in the feed to comments that are days, months, even years old, that haven't been touched in any way. Makes me `o_O` sometimes.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ that's strange. Whant me to add that to the list ?

Comment: @Mekap: No, that's ok. If somebody sees the comment and thinks it's worth investigating I'm sure it will make it onto somebody's list.

Comment: This issue constantly plagues me and I would strongly encourage the staff to Do Something about it. More to the point, does anyone on the staff ever actually **test the UX of Stack Overflow open in multiple tabs**?